# Is there a word(or a combination of 2 words) that describe someone who advances his career using solely underhandedly social relationships?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

I was thinking about social chameleon but it may be a more accurate word(or word combination) for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "underhandedly social relationships"? Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Someone(unqualified) at an academic job getting promoted(at the expense of more qualified people) by having created strong friendships with those responsible for the promotion procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ingratiating,** **sycophantic,** **groveling,** **unctuous,** **obsequious,** and other synonyms could apply to this situation.

These words are all synonyms of each other, so they all have (very) similar meanings.

**Sycophantic** is defined as:

> behaving or done in an obsequious way in order to gain advantage. [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sycophantic)

**Obsequious** is defined as:

> obedient or attentive to an excessive or servile degree. [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/obsequious)

I won't put the rest of the definitions because they are all essentially the same.  However, the "best" word for this situation would likely be "sycophantic" because of the **"to gain advantage"** part of its definition; nonetheless, **all of these words have that as a subtextual component**.

Answer (score 0):

A **corporate climber** or **ladder climber** might fit here.

While I can't find a dictionary definition that affirms these phrases, [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&content=corporate%20climber%2C%20ladder%20climber&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccorporate%20climber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cladder%20climber%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccorporate%20climber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cladder%20climber%3B%2Cc0) certainly supports them.

They are related to the term [social climber](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/social%20climber) which can be found in Merriam-Webster.

Whether you view them as positive, neutral, or negative is really a personal point of view, but increasingly, there are negative connotations.